# Create a JavaScript function dynamically from a string name

Tags: javascript, class, function

Given a string `classname`, I want to dynamically create a new JavaScript function named after that string that can be used to instantiate objects.

I've tried using `eval()` but for some reason the declared function does not appear in the global (window) scope.

```
eval( "function " + classname + "() {}" );
window[ classname ]; // => undefined
```

Is there a way I can dynamically create a new function named after a string?

Or, alternatively, give me some way to reference the created function after creating it via `eval`. Interestingly it appears as a local variable when I debug it in Safari.

**Update:**

Got it! Of course it's obvious, I just use `eval` again to create the instance:

```
var myInstance = eval( "new " + classname );
myInstance.constructor.name; // => classname (yay)
```

This should work in my case because I only need to create one instance of the class right after it's declared. For the general case though see Pointy's answer.

Comment: Admittedly my only real reason for wanting to do this is so the objects appear as instances of "classname" in the debugger. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes:

```
window[classname] = function() { ... };
```

Now, in honesty, that's not *exactly* like what you were attempting, but it's pretty close.  When you instantiate a function via a `function` *expression* like that, and without a name, the function can't refer to itself except via the name in the outer scope (in this case, the global scope).

If that's important, what you could do is this: create the function with some stock "internal" name, and then assign it to the global name:

```
function secretName() { ... }

window[classname] = secretName;
```

Comment: Yeah I'd really like the function to be properly named.

Comment: Giving this the answer because it's the most elegant way to do it, not counting my irrational desire to have the object be a real named function.

Comment: @chaiguy well the thing is you just have to decide whether having the function get the "right" internal name is worth the unpleasantness of using `eval()` when there's a fairly good alternative.

Comment: Actually decided it wasn't and went with your method for cleanliness.

Answer (score 7):

```
function registerFunction(functionBody) {
         "use strict";
         var script = document.createElement("script");
         script.innerHTML = "function " + functionBody;
         document.body.appendChild(script);
}
registerFunction("fooBar(x, y) { return x + y; }");
fooBar(1, 2); // will give you 3
```

Although this is essentially the same as `eval()` but it will register the function in the domain of the current page. You can later remove this script element, or reuse it for other functions.

Comment: Its a different approach. Seems to work fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var classname = "myFunction";

window[ classname ] = function () {};

alert( window[ classname ] ); // => undefined
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you don't want to create new functions based on some string, but based on another similar function: (this might not be a good example but hope you can get the idea)

```
function createListOfFunctions(functionNameList) {
  resultFunctions = {};

  // Loop all names to create a list of functions with those names
  $.each(functionNameList, function(index, functionName) {
    resultFunctions[functionName] = _createFunction(functionName);
  });

  return resultFunctions;
}

function _createFunction(name) {
  return function(anotherNameToCompare) {
    // customize this funciton whatever you like
    return name == anotherNameToCompare;
  };
}


// USAGE:
functionNameList = ['stack', 'overflow'];
result = createListOfFunctions(functionNameList); // result = { stack: function(name) {...}, overflow: function(name) {...} }

result.stack('stack'); // true
result.stack('not stack'); // false
result.overflow('overflow'); // true
```