# Creating functions dynamically in JS

Tags: javascript

I am creating the AI engine for a JS game, and it's made of Finite State Machines. I am loading the number of states and their variable values from the XML. I also want to load the behaviour, and since I don't have the time to create a scripting language, I thought it would be a good idea to 'insert' JS code on external files (inside XML nodes), and execute it on demand.

Something like that

```
<evilguy1>
    <behaviour>
        this.x++;
    </behaviour>
    <behaviour>
        this.y++;
    </behaviour>
</evilguy1>
```

To something like that:

```
function behaviour_1(){
    this.x++;
}
function behaviour_2(){
    this.y++;
}
```

My question is, now that I have the code loaded, how can I execute it? I would like to create a function with an unique name for each code 'node', and then call them from the game logic, but I don't know if this is possible (Since you can load more JS code from the HTML, you should also be able to do it from the JS code, no?). If not, is there any similar solution? Thanks in advance!

(PS:The less external-library-dependent, the better)

Edit 1:

Ok, so now I know how to create functions to contain the code

```
window[classname] = function() { ... };
```

Comment: I think you'll need to elaborate and perhaps show some code...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12964262/create-a-javascript-function-dynamically-from-a-string-name

Comment: `eval`, but be wary of it, since it's evil.

Comment: @Triode Thanks really useful for the naming problem. Now I only have to figure out how to deal with the code loading.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Well, you could use `Function` constructor, like in this example:

```
var f = new Function('name', 'return alert("hello, " + name + "!");');
f('erick');
```

This way you're defining a new function with arguments and body and assigning it to a variable f. You could use a hashset and store many functions:

```
var fs = [];
fs['f1'] = new Function('name', 'return alert("hello, " + name + "!");');
fs['f1']('erick');
```

Loading xml depends if it is running on browser or server.

Comment: Thank you for succinctly answering the question that brought me to this page. Combined with the information added by @MetalGodwin, I successfully solved that issue. Now I have only to address a cross-origin issue, and I should be home free.

Comment: This is approach is not recommended and you should avoid using it as it cause a performance issue. For more information, ready **Cheating Lexical** in chapter two (Lexical Scope) of **You don't know JS Book 2: Scope and Closures**

Comment: if you need to use this inside class, then you don't have access to ```this``` coz it will be pointing to that function.

Answer (score 9):

To extend Ericks answer about the Function constructor.

The Function constructor creates an anonymous function, which on runtime error would print out anonymous for each function (created using Function) in the call stack. Which could make debugging harder.

By using a utility function you can dynamically name your created functions and bypass that dilemma. This example also merges all the bodies of each function inside the functions array into one before returning everything as one named function.

```
const _createFn = function(name, functions, strict=false) {

    var cr = `\n`, a = [ 'return function ' + name + '(p) {' ];

    for(var i=0, j=functions.length; i<j; i++) {
        var str = functions[i].toString();
        var s = str.indexOf(cr) + 1;
        a.push(str.substr(s, str.lastIndexOf(cr) - s));
    }
    if(strict == true) {
        a.splice(1, 0, '\"use strict\";' + cr)
    }
    return new Function(a.join(cr) + cr + '}')();
}
```

A heads up about the Function constructor:

> A function defined by a function expression inherits the current
>   scope. That is, the function forms a closure. On the other hand, a
>   function defined by a Function constructor does not inherit any scope
>   other than the global scope (which all functions inherit).

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#Differences

Comment: Can you please explicit this: "*makes debugging harder*"? Ultimately, an example would be helpful.

Comment: Hello, what I mean is that, upon runtime error, the stack trace and debugger prints out the custom name instead of "anonymous" for each created function. I can update the post.

Comment: Can you show this being called after it's been instantiated? I'm not used to calling the _constant to use a function. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, @MetalGodwin, for posting the citation of the Mozilla document about function constructors, from which I learned much that paved the way for eventually solving the problem that brought me to this page.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you have an array of node names and a parallel array of function body's:

```
var functions = {};
var behaviorsNames = ['behavior1', 'beahvior2'];
var behaviorsBodies = ['this.x++', 'this.y++'];
for (var i = 0; i < behaviorsNames.length; i++){
    functions[behaviorsNames[i]] =  new Function(behaviorsBodies[i]);
}

//run a function
functions.behavior1();
```

or as globals:

```
var behaviorsNames = ['behavior1', 'beahvior2'];
var behaviorsBodies = ['this.x++', 'this.y++'];
for (var i = 0; i < behaviors.length; i++){
    window[behaviors[i]] = new Function(behaviorsBodies[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the above answers use the `new Function()` approach which is not recommended as it effects your app performance. You should totally avoid this approach and use `window[classname] = function() { ... };` as @user3018855 mention in his question.

Comment: reference to "new Function() approach is not recommended" ?

Comment: Read **Cheating Lexical** in chapter two (Lexical Scope) of *You don't know JS Book 2: Scope and Closures* @SimpleFellow