# Executing one function from other JS

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have a java script and I want to have a function which takes a parameter and execute different function that amount of times.

I have something like that for now:

```
<body onLoad="funct1(5)">

<script>
    funct1(a){
        var house = [];
        int x = 20;
        int y = 250;
        for(var i= 0; i<a; i++){
            house [i] = funct2(x,y);
            y=y+50;
        }

        for (var j = 0; j<a; j++){
            house[j]();
        }
    }
</script>

<script>
    funct2(x,y){
    //doing something with that 2 variables, drawing a house.
    } 
</script>
```

I was trying to put that 2 functions in one script but it also didn't work. 
Is there is any possible way to execute one function from another and put it into an array to store it and to draw it afterwards?

Comment: There is no such variable declaration in javascript like `int y = 250;`

Comment: Also, what are you expecting `funct2` to return? If it isn't returning a new function, you can't do `house[j]()`

Comment: @millerbr I want to draw a row of the same houses without creating thousand of same functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do it in one script tag or two, it doesn't matter as anyway the browser will execute them synchronously.
Your variable declarations for x and y are wrong.
Your function declarations are also wrong.
Anyway they are just syntax errors which you shall eventually avoid.

You cannot call "house[j] ()" as you have already executed the function in this statement: "funct2(x,y)".
If you want to store the function calls with the parameters assigned before hand, then you should use : "house [i] = funct2.bind(this, x, y)" i.e. you are binding the parameters to the function whenever it will be called and storing the copy of this callable binded function in house[i].

I suppose this is what you want:

```
<body onLoad="funct1(5)">

<script>
    function funct1(a){
        var house = [];
        var x = 20;
        var y = 250;
        for(var i= 0; i<a; i++){
            house [i] = funct2.bind(this, x, y);
            y=y+50;
        }

        for (var j = 0; j<a; j++){
            house[j]();
        }
    }
</script>

<script>
    function funct2(x,y){
        console.log('drawing house with x '+x+' and y '+y);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, for slow comment, but previous one did not load. Thank you for your corrections, now it is working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

This should work from the same script tag. You need to change the `int x` and `int y` to `var x` and `var y` though:

```
<script>
    var funct1= function(a){
        var house = [];
        var x = 20;
        var y = 250;
        for(var i= 0; i<a; i++){
            house [i] = funct2(x,y);
            y=y+50;
        }

        for (var j = 0; j<a; j++){
            house[j]();
        }
    }
    var funct2 = function(x,y){
    //doing something with that 2 variables, drawing a house.
        return function() { 
            //do stuff with x and y
        }
    } 
</script>
```

`funct2` now returns a function as well, allowing you to call `house[j]()` on the result.

Comment: So I need to create function in function to generate the row of houses after all?

Comment: Yes - if the function is going to change each time, it needs to be generated

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are looking for is actually quite complicated. You want `func2` to return functions based on x and y. Thats possible by defining them dynamically like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20129236/creating-functions-dynamically-in-js) and then return them and save them in the `house` array.

But why would you want to do this? Don't save them in the `house` array and just make func2 paint them directly.