# Extendscript: Dynamically create dropdown lists and onChange functions for them

Tags: javascript, extendscript

Here's a challenging one. I'm relatively new to scripting but have an idea I want to get working.

I have a script that is dynamically generating drop-down lists based on an array: each item in that array creates a `dropdownlist`.

```js
function getDropDownLists(inputArray, grp) { //input an array and the UI Group we're adding these DDLs to
          try {
            eval(grp + "Array = [];"); //Creates an array to store the DDLs we're about to create
            var listName; //Create variable to store name of DDL we're creating as we iterate through inputArray
            for (var i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
              listName = grp + "SrcLevel_" + i.toString(); //Get the name for the DDL we're about to create
              eval('var ' + listName + ' = ' + grp + '.add("dropdownlist",[0,0,150,25])'); //add a DDL for the current array item
              eval(listName + '.add("item","' + listName + '")'); //This line creates an item in each dropdown to tell me its name
              eval(grp + "Array[" + i + "] = " + listName + ";"); //Adds newly created DDL to the storage array
            }
          } catch (e) {
            alert("Error on line " + e.line + ":\n" + e.message);
          }
        }
```

When I call this function (it may not work perfectly here as I've cleaned it up a bit for display purposes) it correctly creates all my `dropdownlists`. However, I want to create `onChange` events for each of these to reference the previous one in the created storage array and change its contents. I know how to make the `onChange` events work if these were known `dropdownlists`, but every project I'll be working on is different and I'd like to get this to work without having to retool every time the project requirements change.

For example, when I call `getDropDownLists(['mom','dad','baby'],family)`, I would get three `dropdownlists`: `familySrcLevel_0`,`familySrcLevel_1`,`familySrcLevel_2`. How would I then create `onClick` events for each of these `dropdownlists`, knowing that I won't always know how many there are? Is such a thing possible? It has to be done in Extendscript.

Comment: I should add that I will need `familySrcLevel_1` to reference the selection of `familySrcLevel_0`, on up the list.

Comment: Sounds complicated. Could you break your problem down in smaller pieces?  Also your code example does not show anything you tried with the `onChange` functions. Last I would suggest getting rid of the `try catch` block and also the `eval` makes your code harder to debug

Comment: Why get rid of the `try catch` block? Isn't its purpose for debugging?

I have to leave the `eval` statements in; they're what allow me to create `dropdownlists` on the fly with unique variable names so I can reference them earlier.

Comment: Well if you think so. I always found using try catch kind of dirty. You could go for some resource strings (Adobe JS Tools guide page 79 [link](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/scripting/pdfs/javascript_tools_guide.pdf)) to generate your UI without using eval. But I think you cant create functions with them.

Comment: If I knew what the UI were always going to be, I wouldn't need to use `eval`. But because depending on different projects, the input array could change, I don't always know how many `dropdownlists` I'll need. So I'm dynamically creating the UI based on that array so that I don't need to rewrite the script every time that changes. It allows me to reference those `dropdownlists` by giving them uniquely generated names as well, so children `dropdownlists` can change their content based on parent `dropdownlists`.

Comment: I think that is the reason why there are resource strings. You can create them dynamically without using stringifyed js code. But hey. If it works for you. ;) I always have that little voice in my head calling the term "eval is eeeeeevvviiilll" when I reach the l of eval

Comment: What is it about `eval` that is so bad? it seems simpler than trying to create a resource string when I need to create `onChange` functions for the `dropdownlists` using `eval` anyway.

Comment: About eval: https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=de&q=Eval%20is%20evil about function creation on the fly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20129236/creating-functions-dynamically-in-js but you are right the function creation is like eval. Is it only the naming that is dynamic or do you need also a dynamic behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to create another `eval` statement that contained the `onChange` function in it at the end of the function above.